# Do you need to back up (not snapshot, but full copy of data) DB if you have Multi-AZ standby DB instances?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, backup, fault-tolerance

I understand that database backup is a full copy of the database and serves as the last resort in a disaster where data is lost -- recovering data.

In the case of multi-AZ standby db deployment, we already have multiple copies of the data, thus it's unlikely that all of them will be destroyed. With that in mind, do we still need database backup in this case? Or we can just use the other standby instances as backup?

Note that I'm not talking about snapshot here. I do understand we still need to take snapshots to revert changes in case of an accidental change or human error.

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi-AZ is backup only within **same region**. It does not protect you from data loss caused by entire region outage or destruction.

For mission critical databases you can either create read replica in a [different region](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ReadRepl.XRgn.html) for live backups, or a cheaper solution is to [copy db snapshots to different region](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/cross-region-snapshot-copy-for-amazon-rds/) on periodic basis.

Comment: Thank you. I think what you suggested is quite reasonable. To confirm, as @Riz also suggested db snapshot copy, is this db snapshot copy capable of recover corrupted / destructed / lost data?

Comment: @somenickname Yes, snapshot is a full copy of your databases. But its not done in real-time, only when you request it.

Comment: Are you implying there is some kind of realtime backup?

Comment: @somenickname Read replica in a different region would be such backup. For same region you have multi az.

Answer (score 1):

What I do not undersdtand here is the emphasis on the word **backup**. RDS snapshot is a whole backup of the instance. You can recover the whole rds instance with all the settings from the snapshot. So it's a **backup**.
It's better to have a backup retention policy from 1(0 being no backup) upto 35 days(which by the way are snapshots).
As Marcin already talked about, it's better to have a read replica which can help with performance as well as can act like a backup. Anything happens to the main db, you can promote read replica to the main.

Comment: I believe snapshot only captures point-in-time state of the database so you can revert back to that point-in-time. That means if the actual database data is lost / corrupted, snapshot is useless, whereas an actual (full-copy) backup can survive disaster events like destruction, thus the ask.

Comment: @somenickname, nope, it's absolutely not like you think. We use snapshots to create full db almost 5 times a month and trust me it's full db.